# How to add back navigation functionality to standard SAPUI5 application 'ar_srvc_news'?

Tags: rss, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have configured a news tile in Fiori Launchpad and linked the `ar_srvc_news` (found in the `SPBUTIL` role in `lpd_cust`) UI5 application to it. Is there a way to enable back navigation functionality in it similar to the one that exists in SAP Fiori Trial website (highlighted in below image)?

[image: SAP Fiori Trial News Tile]

The tile configured in our system opens the News application without any header. I checked the BSP application `AR_SRVC_NEWS` in `SE80` and the view that displays these news items is *NewsTileDrillDown.view.js*. The navigation button that allows back navigation has not been enabled in it. I assume we set the `showNavButton` for `sap.m.Page` to be true to enable this functionality. Feel free to correct me if this is not correct.

Also, a blank window opens up upon clicking on any of the news items. The application is displaying `sap.suite.ui.commons.FeedItemHeader` for displaying the news items. How to disable this navigation? I observed that in SAP Fiori Trial website, only the last news item is clickable and opens a new window. We are following the same RSS feed hierarchy as the website's but this does not help.